# how to generate py files without default windows crlf?

Tags: python, code-generation, eval

how can I write a .py file from python such that its type should not be like 'ASCII file with Windows CRLF'

because when i run `file.write(data)` inside windows it write the file but when I try to 
`eval(open(file.py).read())` it fails and gives syntax error because of windows CRLF on each line......

see the error log - traceback

```
ERROR:web-services:[25]:     info = eval(tools.file_open(terp_file).read(-1))
ERROR:web-services:[26]:   File "<string>", line 1
ERROR:web-services:[27]:     {
ERROR:web-services:[28]:
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? and why?

Comment: Maybe you can give a look at the rstrip funcion.

Comment: @SilentGhost I believe he's trying to write a code generation tool (hence the tag).

Comment: yes, you are right its a code generator tool, where I'm simply writing the dictionary {"name":"Hello"} it works fine with linux but not for windows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Write the file in binary mode by opening it with `open(file, 'wb')` or...
2. Strip the CR-LFs from the string before writing it with something like `data.replace('\r','')`

I would steer clear of `exec` and use `execfile` [as mentioned by SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737208/how-to-generate-py-files-without-default-windows-crlf/2737242#2737242).

Comment: Thanks D.Shawley I don't know why but it worked with 'wb' it,
it should also work for 'w' - anyhow thanks for your immediate help !

Comment: @shahjapan - there is a good Wikipedia link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages) that describes the differences between _"binary mode"_ and _"text mode"_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the CRLF, but that `eval` is for evaluating a single expression, not an entire program.

You can use `exec` to execute a program from a string, or `execfile` to execute it directly from a file.

To answer your original question anyway, you can avoid writing CRLF by opening the file in binary mode: `f = open(filename, 'wb')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) function.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file in binary mode: `open("myfile.py", "rwb")`